How can I resolve the error in the code for the chrome-extension that overwrites google-meet's facial images in real time?

The URL after https://meet.google.com/ is not set properly and refers to a js file.



document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild) in the loader.js is giving me an error, can't I use it in manifestV3?


The error message displayed is as follows.
　※The detailed error text could not be posted because the site was flagged as spam.

It seems that there is an error especially here
・loader.js
document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild)



Refused to load the script 'https://meet.google.com/tf-core.js' because it violates the  Content Security Policy directive

We think it is strange that the js file is referenced behind https://meet.google here for some reason.


Refused to execute inline script because it violates the Content Security Policy directive

Uncaught (in promise) Event
Context
https://meet.google.com/
Stack trace
loader.js:36 (Unnamed function)


extension.sh is the code to download the js files in the code. This shell was used to download the files.

Folder structure
extension
-face-kandmarks-detection.js
-ImMarkIMG.js
-extensions.sh
-main.js
-loader.js
-manifest.json
-tf-backend-webgl.js
-tf-converter.js
-tf-core.js



extensions.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#NOTE: if you are on macOS, update to bash v4 i.e brew install bash

rm -rf extension extension.zip
cp -r public extension 
cd extension
 
declare -A scripts0=(
    [file]='tf-core.js'
    [url]='https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-core@2.4.0/dist/tf-core.js'
)
declare -A scripts1=(
    [file]='tf-converter.js'
    [url]='https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter@2.4.0/dist/tf-converter.js'
)
declare -A scripts2=(
    [file]='tf-backend-webgl.js'
    [url]='https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@2.4.0/dist/tf-backend-webgl.js'
)
declare -A scripts3=(
    [file]='face-landmarks-detection.js'
    [url]='https://unpkg.com/@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection@0.0.1/dist/face-landmarks-detection.js'
)

declare -n scripts
for scripts  in ${!scripts@}; do
  curl ${scripts[url]} -o ${scripts[file]}
  sed -i"" -e "s|${scripts[url]}|${scripts[file]}|g" main.js
done

zip -r extension.zip *
mv extension.zip ../




manifest.js
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Meet Face Hack Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Meet hack",
    "host_permissions": [
    "https://meet.google.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["lmMarkImg.js","tf-core.js","tf-converter.js","tf-　backend-webgl.js","face-landmarks-detection.js","loader.js","main.js"],
      "matches": ["https://meet.google.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}


loader.js
function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = src
    script.onload = () => {
      console.log(`loaded: ${src}`)
      resolve()
    }
    script.onerror = (e) => reject(e)
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild)
  })
}

async function loadLocalScript(path) {
  const res = await fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(path), {method: 'GET'})
  const text = await res.text()
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.textContent = text
  document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild)
}


async function load() {
  loadLocalScript("lmMarkImg.js")
  
  await loadScript("tf-core.js")
  await loadScript("tf-converter.js")
  await loadScript("tf-backend-webgl.js")
  await loadScript("face-landmarks-detection.js")

  loadLocalScript("main.js")
}

window.addEventListener('load', async (evt) => {
  await load()
})

main.js
const video = document.createElement('video')
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext('2d')
let model = null
let keepAnimation = false

let imageIndex = 0
function getImage() {
  const image = lmMarkImages[imageIndex]
  imageIndex += 1
  if (imageIndex == lmMarkImages.length) {
    imageIndex = 0
  }

  return image
}

function drawImage(prediction) {
  let imageIndex = 0
  const boundingBox = prediction.boundingBox
  const x = boundingBox.topLeft[0]
  const y = boundingBox.topLeft[1]
  const w = boundingBox.bottomRight[0] - x
  const h = boundingBox.bottomRight[1] - y

  // draw Rectangle for debug
  // canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  // canvasCtx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h)

  const image = getImage()
  canvasCtx.drawImage(image, x, y, w, h)
}

async function updateCanvas() {
  if (!keepAnimation) return

  if (model) {
    canvasCtx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    const predictions = await model.estimateFaces({ input: video })
    for (const prediction of predictions) {
      drawImage(prediction)
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas)
}

function isScreenSharing(constraints) {
  return !constraints.video.deviceId
}

function replaceStopFunction(stream, videoTrack) {
  if (!videoTrack) return

  videoTrack._stop = videoTrack.stop
  videoTrack.stop = function () {
    keepAnimation = false
    videoTrack._stop()
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      track.stop()
    })
  }
}

const _getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.bind(
  navigator.mediaDevices
)

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = async function (constraints) {
  const srcStream = await _getUserMedia(constraints)

  if (isScreenSharing(constraints)) {
    return srcStream
  }

  video.srcObject = srcStream
  video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
    video.play()
    video.volume = 0.0
    video.width = video.videoWidth
    video.height = video.videoHeight
    canvas.width = video.width
    canvas.height = video.height

    keepAnimation = true
    updateCanvas()
  }

  const outStream = canvas.captureStream(10)
  const videoTrack = outStream.getVideoTracks()[0]
  replaceStopFunction(srcStream, videoTrack)

  return outStream
}

async function loadModel() {
  model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
    faceLandmarksDetection.SupportedPackages.mediapipeFacemesh
  )
  //console.log("model: loaded")
}

function main() {
  loadModel()
}

main()



Because it was necessary to paste a minimal amount of code, main.js was not pasted. I will add it if necessary.

Folder structure has been modified.


Content scripts running in the default ISOLATED world in ManifestV3 can't set textContent of a script element. Use src with chrome.runtime.getURL.
Don't call loadScript for tf scripts, because you don't have them, they are part of main.js.

Here's the entire loader.js:
const scripts = [
  'lmMarkImg.js',
  'main.js',
];
(function loadSequentially() {
  const el = document.createElement('script')
  el.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(scripts.shift());
  if (scripts[0]) el.onload = loadSequentially;
  document.documentElement.appendChild(el);
  el.remove();
})();


Thank you so much for answering my question. I would be happy to answer additional questions if possible. main.js has been added to the question.
I got the following error in main.js.
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: faceLandmarksDetection is not defined

Context：
https://meet.google.com/~~~　(this is my meet link)
Stack Trace：
model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(


See the fixed answer.

Do you know how to resolve this error?

As I said I've fixed the answer, use the new code. If it still doesn't work it means you didn't use extensions.sh or it's broken. When used correctly your main.js should contain all these tf scripts.

You may want to use browserify instead of extensions.sh and simply import each package in main.js, then run browserify on it to make the output file that contains all imported code. This output file should be used in the final extension instead of the original main.js.

Changing to the modified version of the code provided did not resolve the error.
The faceLandmarksDetection references face-landmarks-detection.js, but the

typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', '@tensorflow/tfjs-core', '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.faceLandmarksDetection = {}, global.tf, global.tf));
 

Is it possible that "global.tf" is preventing the reference?

Thank you for the "browserify" suggestion. I don't know how to use this one, so I'm looking into it now.

Maybe document.documentElement.appendChild(el) is not working because the package does not contain html? Sorry if I'm wrong.

It runs in the web page, so documentElement is always there.

I understood .
So what do you think about global.tf?(3 previous comments)

If you use browserify correctly it'll solve the problem because it'll produce a single bundle.

When using browserify, do I need to add or rewrite any new code? Is this a problem that can be solved only on the command line?

Please see the demo/documentation for browserify. AFAIK it's really simple: just import or require the modules in main.js, then run browserify and use the output file. You can do the same manually of course by downloading the scripts and concatenating them and putting inside IIFE for isolation (this is what your extensions.sh is supposed to do but apparently it's incorrect).

import * as faceLandmarksDetection from '@tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection';
I thought I could do it with, but I got an error. I also got an error when I tried to run
$ npm install @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection
I did $ npm install @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection

and was told that there was a conflict with another js file because it was a different version.
I looked at the browserify/demo, and after rewriting the code to let require=~, I rewrote package.json (I don't know...) and added npm install @tensorflow-models/face-landmarks-detection  and was told that there was a conflict because the other js files were different versions. and do npm install {module}. Sorry for asking so many times, please let me know how to solve this problem.

I think you should simply import/require the same CDN urls you currently use in extension.sh.

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: faceLandmarksDetection is not defined
model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
I thought I had to "import" it, but maybe I should rewrite loader.js?

Why do you load these files as script elements and not just list them in "content_scripts" as "js"?

What do you mean by that, I assume you mean manifest.js, how do you think it should be fixed?

Just put the scripts in the extension directory and list them in content_scripts->js instead of loader.js and web_accessible_resources.

Fixed manifest.js.
However, the following code is not
 model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load(
part of the model = await faceLandmarksDetection.load()' part says Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: faceLandmarksDetection is not defined.
error persists.

Scripts listed in js run in the listed order, so face-landmarks-detection.js should be listed before the scripts that use it.

Fixed manifest.json. The error has been resolved, but lmMarkImage.js is not applied and the face is not overwritten with the image. If you know anything, please let me know.

Try adding "world": "MAIN" to content_scripts declaration.

The error statement Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getURL is not a function appears in this section. In addition, a note Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found. Consider importing the CPU backend (@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu) for better performance.Is this a problem with my PC?

You don't need chrome.runtime.getURL, no need to create script elements with this approach. Regarding the error message, it says you didn't add tfjs-backend-cpu.js, so just add it or try googling the error message or ask in the forum/repository for this package.

I rewrote the js part of content_scripts in manifest and it works correctly. "js": ["tf-core.js", "tf-converter.js", "tf-backend-webgl.js", "face-landmarks-detection.js", "lmMarkImg.js", "loader.js", "main.js",
Thank you very much indeed. I couldn't have done it without you.

However, the error has not been resolved....

The image breaks up every 2 seconds.
Can I delete the getURL line?


You don't need loader.js, remove it.

Loader.js has been removed. Your application contains ops that are small enough to be executed on the CPU backend, however the CPU backend cannot be found. backend (@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu) for better performance. is displayed. I guess @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu is not a js file, but a directory, so I have to import it using webpack or something. The error message is as follows. console.warn('Your application contains ops that are small enough to be 

I assume this is why the image breaks up every two seconds.

Try making a new question with tags for tensorflow so its experts could help.
